# replace indices in matrix with other values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Suppose now I have a matrix

```
S = [1 1 1 2 2 2;
     1 1 1 2 2 2;
     2 2 2 2 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 1 1;
     2 2 2 2 1 1]
```

And another matrix

```
A = [1 2;
     2 4]
```

The first row in A is the unique indices of S, and the second row contains the values that the values in the first row will be replaced. That is, all "1"s in S will be replaced by 2, and all "2"s will be replaced by 4. Finally I'll get a matrix

```
SS = [2 2 2 4 4 4;
      2 2 2 4 4 4;
      4 4 4 4 2 2;
      4 4 4 4 2 2;
      4 4 4 4 2 2]
```

Right now what I'm doing is:

```
SS = zeros(size(S));
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    SS(S==index(A(1, i)) = A(2,i);
end
```

Now, I have a pretty big matrix, and using a for loop is a little bit slow. Is there a faster way to do that?

Comment: You said "1"s will be replaced by "2"s, but `SS` still has "1"s... a mistake?

Comment: @EitanT Sorry for that, already edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of `ismember` to give you indices of the values in row 1 of A.  Use these indices to directly create matrix `SS`.

Example (changed initial values for clarity):

> > S = [5 5 5 3 3 3;
> >              5 5 5 3 3 3;
> >              3 3 3 3 5 5;
> >              3 3 3 3 5 5;
> >              3 3 3 3 5 5];
> >     A = [5 3;
> >              2 4];

```
>> [~, Locb] = ismember(S,A(1,:))
Locb =

     1     1     1     2     2     2
     1     1     1     2     2     2
     2     2     2     2     1     1
     2     2     2     2     1     1
     2     2     2     2     1     1

>> SS = reshape(A(2,Locb),size(S))
SS =

     2     2     2     4     4     4
     2     2     2     4     4     4
     4     4     4     4     2     2
     4     4     4     4     2     2
     4     4     4     4     2     2
```

Comment: +1 Neat. Can you add a comparison of execution times with my solution (I'm not near MATLAB right now)?

Comment: @EitanT It's about 100 times faster than your solution. But thanks anyway, really learned a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, I would use numpy array instead of standard python arrays or lists. Then the code becomes very simple as shown below:

```
# Import numpy
from numpy import array, zeros, shape
# Create the array S
S = array([[1,1,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,1,1],[2,2,2,2,1,1],[2,2,2,2,1,1]])
# Create the array A
A = array([[1,2],[2,4]])
# Create the empty array SS
SS = zeros((shape(S)))
# Actual operation needed 
SS[S==A[0,0]]=A[1,0]
SS[S==A[0,1]]=A[1,1]
```

Now if you see the array SS, it will look as follows:

```
SS
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Sorry for the confusion earlier. I had (for some reason) assumed that this question was for Python (my bad!). Anyways, the answer for MATLAB is very similar:

```
SS = zeros(size(S))
SS(S==A(1,1))=A(2,1)
SS(S==A(1,2))=A(2,2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my tag is "matlab", sorry for the mis-understanding.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Actually I was myself looking for something regarding Python/Mayavi when I stumbled upon this question. And as I probably knew the answer, I just jumped in the help without looking at the tags. Next time I will be careful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could go about this with an [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html;jsessionid=bcbd8aa4deea3ab1700cd140f825) one-liner, like this:

```
SS = arrayfun(@(x)A(2, (A(1, :) == x),  S)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, what if the indices in matrix S are not continuous, say the "2"s in S is "3". If this happens, I think I can only change the matrix A to add some entries in order to use your suggested codes. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: what I mean is, for a new matrix S, its indices are 1 or 3. And A contains information of say, 1->2, 3->6. In this case I couldn't use your suggested codes, because in your codes, n represent not only the column number of A, but also the actual value of S. As a consequence, either of your suggestions couldn't work because we'll meet an index exceeding error.

Comment: Oh I see. Please try my revised answer then. See if it's faster.

Comment: `arrayfun` is generally not faster than a basic for loop unfortunately. It's worth testing - I'd like to see the results of a speed test - but I'm not hopeful for an increase in speed with this method.